# Does the boundary of a level set of a Lipschitz continuous function have Lebesgue measure $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a (bounded, if necessary) Lipschitz continuous function. Are we able to show that $\partial f^{-1}\left(\left\{0\right\}\right)$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. If not, are there mild conditions under which the claim holds true?

I don't have much to contribute, since I struggle to find a good starting point.

**EDIT**: The question seems to be related to the notion of [Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure)s and maybe [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem). Since I've never heard about Hausdorff measures before reading the Wikipedia article, I hope there is a solution to this problem which doesn't need this concept.

Comment: Hint: Every closed subset can be realized as zero level set of  1-Lipschitz function.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's clear to me. If $(E,d)$ is a metric space and $A\subseteq E$, then $E\ni x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous. And if $A$ is closed, its zero level set is precisely $A$. But I don't see how this helps here.

Comment: Take a Cantor set of positive linear measure...

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you elaborate on your approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C\subset {\mathbb R}$ be a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), i.e. a subset of ${\mathbb R}$ which has positive Lebesgue measure and is homeomorphic to the standard Cantor set (i.e. is nonempty, compact, perfect and has empty interior). Let $f(x)=d(x,C)$ be the distance function to $C$. As you know, $f$ is 1-Lipschitz. At the same time, $C=f^{-1}(0)= \partial C$ (since $C$ has empty interior). With a bit more work one can replace $f$ with a function $g$ which is infinitely differentiable on ${\mathbb R}$ and still have $C=g^{-1}(0)$.

As for Sard's theorem, it is about **images** not preimages, so is unrelated to your question.

Related: [The Boundary of a Lipschitz domain has Lebesgue measure zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900015/the-boundary-of-a-lipschitz-domain-has-lebesgue-measure-zero?rq=1)

Comment: Any set  which is closed and nowhere dense and of positive measure  will do . So if we want  $f$ to be bounded , replace $C$ with $C\cup \Bbb Z.$................+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet sure

Comment: Does the situation change if $f$ is assumed to be continuously differentiable? In that case, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, it is not a submanifold. You can even get infinitely differentiable function.

Comment: Sorry, I've intended to assume that $0$ is a regular value of $f$. Asked for that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3218322/47771.

Comment: @0xbadf00d then of course this holds by the implicit function theorem : even Lipschitz hypersurface has measure zero.

Comment: It's clear to me that $\{f=0\}$ has measure zero by the implicit function theorem, but not how we can show this for the boundary. If you know how we can show it (under the assumption that $0$ is a regular value), then it would be great if you could provide an answer to the other question.

Comment: The hypersurface $\{f=0\}$ (if $0$ is a regular value) has empty interior and equals its own boundary.